# Group each dynamically generated form into an array

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I am generating some forms which i have grouped into groups of four form fields like so http://options-html5.herokuapp.com/   `--> see other information tab`

This is my jquery code that generates the form

```
//Add Partner
$('.partner_create_button').on('click',function(){


   $('<article class="crud_item">
<span class="delete_partner">Delete Partner</span><br/>
<label class="name_label">Partner Name</label>
<input class="text_element" type="text" name="partner_crud[]" placeholder="partner name" />
<label class="name_label">Partner URL</label>
<input class="text_element" type="text" name="partner_crud[]" placeholder="partner url"/>
<label class="name_label">Partner Logo</label>
<input  class="text_element"type="text" name="partner_crud[]" placeholder="partner logo" />
<span class="get_image_from_the_media_centre">Get Image From Media Centre</span>
<label class="name_label">Partner Status</label>
<select class="text_element" name="partner_crud[]">
<option value="partner status" selected>Select your option</option>  
<option>Published</option> 
<option>Pending Approval</option>
<option>In Future</option>
</select>
</article>').appendTo('.partners_holder');
```

However when i submit the form and process the `$_POST` i get this

```
[partner_crud] => Array
        (
            [0] => partner name
            [1] => partner url
            [2] => partner logo
            [3] => partner status
            [4] => partner name
            [5] => partner url
            [6] => partner logo
            [7] => partner status
            [8] => partner name
            [9] => partner url
            [10] => partner logo
            [11] => partner status
            [12] => partner name
            [13] => partner url
            [14] => partner logo
            [15] => partner status
            [16] => partner name
            [17] => partner url
            [18] => partner logo
            [19] => partner status
        )
```

The posted fields are all in one array.Is there a way i can fix my form to get this format of the posted values?

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => partner name
            [1] => partner url
            [2] => partner logo
            [3] => partner status
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => partner name
            [1] => partner url
            [2] => partner logo
            [3] => partner status
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => partner name
            [1] => partner url
            [2] => partner logo
            [3] => partner status
        )
```

In the above,each form gets its own array.

Comment: sounds like a job for http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**array_chunk**](https://www.php.net/array_chunk),

```
print_r(array_chunk($a,4));
```

**Note:** Though I will suggest you better to give fields name such that you get array in your desired way.

Comment: You should be aware, that this way is highly dependent on POST data, for example, if user delete single input in firebug in your application you will get total mess.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to put every set of inputs inside separate array by changing names to:

```
name="partner_crud[$i][]"
```

Every time you add new inputs via jquery $i should be increased, so you should keep track of current count.

Comment: Isn't `$i` a php variable on the client side?

Comment: You can call variable as you want, this should be javascript variable, and it's value should be put and increased every time you add input set i.e. partner_crud[1][], partner_crud[2][]

Comment: I have `var i = 0; ` and using the var here `name="partner_crud[i][]"` however the `i` is not being used.How should i get the `i` to be seen ? Edit trying out this `partner_crud['+i+'][]`

Comment: I did `var i = 0;
i +=1;` but this does not seem to work for now.